# How do I filter a first event per day per group, select a variable in another column based on a condition, and run calculations on values inbetween?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, conditional-statements, posixct

In R, I have a data frame with the columns id (representing study participants), phase, time, glucose, steps, and kiloCalories. **id** and **phase** are *factors*, **time** is *POSIXcT* and includes date + time, **glucose** (sampled every ~15 minutes) **steps** (sampled every minute), and **kiloCalories** (sampled irregularly, represents an eaten meal) are *numeric*.
Glucose and kiloCalories data is much less frequently sampled than steps, so it contains lots of NAs.

I would like to filter this data frame in the following ways:

1. Retrieve the rows with the first meal of the day of each participant (id), and their glucose reading 2 hours (+-15 minutes) **before** that meal.
2. Retrieve the rows with each meal (i.e. each kiloCalories entry) of each participant (id), along with the glucose reading 2 hours (+-15 minutes) **after** the meal.
3. From task 2, take the subset of data in between meal and glucose reading, and calculate the sum of steps within that time.

The reason I specify 2 hours **(+-15 minutes)** is because there is a very low probability that the data frame has a glucose reading **exactly** 2 hours after a meal is eaten, thus I want to extend the timeframe

I've tried [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51466759/r-filtering-selecting-data-by-posixct-time-and-a-condition) on how to subset based on time and condition, but to no avail, leaving me stuck at my first task. And that thread does not talk about the complex subsetting I'd like to perform.

Edit - Here is some sample data which meets the criteria of the tasks:

```r
sampleData <- structure(list(id = c(13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 13, 13), phase = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time = structure(c(1450881900, 
1450881960, 1450882020, 1450882080, 1450882140, 1450882200, 1450882260, 
1450882320, 1450882380, 1450882440, 1450882500, 1450882560, 1450882620, 
1450882680, 1450882740, 1450882800, 1450882860, 1450882920, 1450882980, 
1450883040, 1450883100, 1450883160, 1450883220, 1450883280, 1450883340, 
1450883400, 1450883460, 1450883520, 1450883580, 1450883640, 1450883700, 
1450883760, 1450883820, 1450883880, 1450883940, 1450884000, 1450884060, 
1450884120, 1450884180, 1450884240, 1450884300, 1450884360, 1450884420, 
1450884480, 1450884540, 1450884600, 1450884660, 1450884720, 1450884780, 
1450884840, 1450884900, 1450884960, 1450885020, 1450885080, 1450885140, 
1450885200, 1450885260, 1450885320, 1450885380, 1450885440, 1450885500, 
1450885560, 1450885620, 1450885680, 1450885740, 1450885800, 1450885860, 
1450885920, 1450885980, 1450886040, 1450886100, 1450886160, 1450886220, 
1450886280, 1450886340, 1450886400, 1450886460, 1450886520, 1450886580, 
1450886640, 1450886700, 1450886760, 1450886820, 1450886880, 1450886940, 
1450887000, 1450887060, 1450887120, 1450887180, 1450887240, 1450887300, 
1450887360, 1450887420, 1450887480, 1450887540, 1450887600, 1450887660, 
1450887720, 1450887780, 1450887840, 1450887900, 1450887960, 1450888020, 
1450888080, 1450888140, 1450888200, 1450888260, 1450888320, 1450888380, 
1450888440, 1450888500, 1450888560, 1450888620, 1450888680, 1450888740, 
1450888800, 1450888860, 1450888920, 1450888980, 1450889040, 1450889100, 
1450889160, 1450889220, 1450889280, 1450889340, 1450889400, 1450889460, 
1450889520, 1450889580, 1450889640, 1450889700, 1450889760, 1450889820, 
1450889880, 1450889940, 1450890000, 1450890060, 1450890120, 1450890180, 
1450890240, 1450890300, 1450890360, 1450890420, 1450890480, 1450890540, 
1450890600, 1450890660, 1450890720, 1450890780, 1450890840, 1450890900, 
1450890960, 1450891020, 1450891080, 1450891140, 1450891200, 1450891260, 
1450891320, 1450891380, 1450891440, 1450891500, 1450891560, 1450891620, 
1450891680, 1450891740, 1450891800, 1450891860, 1450891920, 1450891980, 
1450892040, 1450892100, 1450892160, 1450892220, 1450892280, 1450892340, 
1450892400, 1450892460, 1450892520, 1450892580, 1450892640, 1450892700, 
1450892760, 1450892820, 1450892880, 1450892940, 1450893000, 1450893060, 
1450893120, 1450893180, 1450893240, 1450893300, 1450893360, 1450893420, 
1450893480, 1450893540, 1450893600, 1450893660, 1450893720, 1450893780, 
1450893840, 1450893900, 1450893960, 1450894020, 1450894080, 1450894140, 
1450894140, 1450894200, 1450894260, 1450894320, 1450894380, 1450894440, 
1450894500, 1450894560, 1450894620, 1450894680, 1450894740, 1450894800, 
1450894860, 1450894920, 1450894980, 1450895040, 1450895100, 1450895160, 
1450895220, 1450895280, 1450895340, 1450895400, 1450895460, 1450895520, 
1450895580, 1450895640, 1450895700, 1450895760, 1450895820, 1450895880, 
1450895940, 1450896000, 1450896060, 1450896120, 1450896180, 1450896240, 
1450896300, 1450896360, 1450896420, 1450896480, 1450896540, 1450896600, 
1450896660, 1450896720, 1450896780, 1450896840, 1450896900, 1450896960, 
1450897020, 1450897080, 1450897140, 1450897200, 1450897260, 1450897320, 
1450897380, 1450897440, 1450897500, 1450897560, 1450897620, 1450897680, 
1450897740, 1450897800, 1450897860, 1450897920, 1450897980, 1450898040, 
1450898100, 1450898160, 1450898220, 1450898280, 1450898340, 1450898400, 
1450898460, 1450898520, 1450898580, 1450898640, 1450898700, 1450898760, 
1450898820, 1450898880, 1450898940, 1450899000, 1450899060, 1450899120, 
1450899180, 1450899240, 1450899300, 1450899360, 1450899420, 1450899480, 
1450899540, 1450899600, 1450899660, 1450899720, 1450899780, 1450899840, 
1450899900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), gl = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 84, NA, NA, NA, NA, 83, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 81, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 82, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 84, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 83, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 79, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
76, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 78, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 93, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 116, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 128, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 141, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 142, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 146, 
143, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
136, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
129, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
134, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
139, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
134, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
128, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), steps = c(24, 39, 28, 19, 29, 6, 
12, 3, 13, 1, 6, 2, 1, 13, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 33, 27, 17, 27, 
30, 19, 23, 34, 38, 25, 30, 42, 31, 31, 16, 52, 91, 39, 23, 7, 
6, 27, 64, 20, 53, 22, 14, 14, 5, 4, 13, 7, 13, 7, 8, 10, 14, 
26, 25, 19, 23, 35, 23, 15, 13, 12, 11, 27, 21, 25, 27, 4, 8, 
18, 15, 22, 30, 16, 15, 15, 5, 3, 4, 6, 0, 12, 10, 4, 3, 5, 2, 
5, 10, 13, 7, 2, 6, 2, 1, 15, 23, 25, 18, 27, 5, 11, 22, 31, 
17, 27, 19, 2, 0, 12, 3, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 5, 4, 
4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 4, 8, 2, 4, 0, 4, 6, 8, 11, 10, 22, 2, 1, 0, 4, 
4, 2, 2, 9, 19, 8, 11, 7, 7, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 13, 9, 0, 3, 4, 
5, 5, 7, 5, 5, 8, 8, 26, 23, 26, 27, 24, 24, 13, 25, 17, 24, 
24, 11, 16, 15, 25, 21, 18, 11, 16, 19, 2, 0, 7, 6, 6, 3, 1, 
13, 13, 0, 1, 10, 12, 10, 9, 7, 1, 1, 12, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 2, 5, 
2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 5, 11, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 10, 13, 1, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
23, 22, 11, 16, 16, 5, 5, 5, 3, 14, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 
3, 1), kiloCalories = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 603, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 143, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -302L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome. Please share your data using ``dput()``. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, @user438383 I just added some data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there may be a number of considerations on how you want to organize your data, depending on how you intend to analyze further. However, here are some ideas that may be helpful for you.

This solution uses `tidyverse` and `fuzzyjoin` as you tagged with `dplyr` - but you may want to consider a `data.table` or `sqldf` solution as alternatives, depending on size of data, speed needed, and other factors.

First, I would create a table that includes the meals based on `kiloCalories` values that are not missing. We will create a `meal` column and enumerate meals for each date. In addition, we can calculate your windows for preprandial and postprandial glucose levels.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

mealsData <- sampleData %>%
  filter(!is.na(kiloCalories)) %>%
  group_by(id, date = date(time)) %>%
  mutate(meal = 1:n(),
         preprandial_1 = time - (60 * 60 * 2) - (15 * 60),
         preprandial_2 = time - (60 * 60 * 2) + (15 * 60),
         postprandial_1 = time + (60 * 60 * 2) - (15 * 60),
         postprandial_2 = time + (60 * 60 * 2) + (15 * 60)) %>%
  select(-gl, -steps, -kiloCalories)
```

The result is this for `mealsData`:

```
     id phase time                date        meal preprandial_1       preprandial_2       postprandial_1      postprandial_2     
  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <date>     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>             
1    13     1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00
2    13     1 2015-12-23 13:30:00 2015-12-23     2 2015-12-23 11:15:00 2015-12-23 11:45:00 2015-12-23 15:15:00 2015-12-23 15:45:00
```

I have found such tables to be very useful as reference.

Next, you can merge this table with your `sampleData`. For task 1, you want preprandial first meal glucose levels. So, you can use `fuzzy_join` and ensure the times are between the calculated preprandial times determined.

```
fuzzy_inner_join(
  mealsData %>% filter(meal == 1),
  sampleData %>% filter(!is.na(gl)),
  by = c("id", "phase", "preprandial_1" = "time", "preprandial_2" = "time"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`)
)
```

The result is:

```
   id.x phase.x time.x              date        meal preprandial_1       preprandial_2       postprandial_1      postprandial_2       id.y phase.y time.y                 gl steps kiloCalories
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <date>     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1    13       1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00    13       1 2015-12-23 09:53:00    84    13           NA
2    13       1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00    13       1 2015-12-23 09:58:00    83    13           NA
3    13       1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00    13       1 2015-12-23 10:08:00    81     3           NA
```

It appears there are 3 glucose levels that fall within that window from the sample data.

Next, you can do something similar for postprandial data, for all meals:

```
fuzzy_inner_join(
  mealsData,
  sampleData %>% filter(!is.na(gl)),
  by = c("id", "phase", "postprandial_1" = "time", "postprandial_2" = "time"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`)
)
```

The result is:

```
   id.x phase.x time.x              date        meal preprandial_1       preprandial_2       postprandial_1      postprandial_2       id.y phase.y time.y                 gl steps kiloCalories
  <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <date>     <int> <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dttm>              <dbl>   <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1    13       1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00    13       1 2015-12-23 13:54:00   134     0           NA
2    13       1 2015-12-23 12:00:00 2015-12-23     1 2015-12-23 09:45:00 2015-12-23 10:15:00 2015-12-23 13:45:00 2015-12-23 14:15:00    13       1 2015-12-23 14:09:00   139     1           NA
```

Here there are two glucose levels postprandial found.

Finally, you can merge the data.frames and then group by the `id` (`id.x` used since the join created a duplicate), the `meal` and the `date`. Then you can sum up the steps:

```
fuzzy_inner_join(
  mealsData,
  sampleData,
  by = c("id", "phase", "time" = "time", "postprandial_2" = "time"),
  match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, `<=`, `>=`)
) %>%
  group_by(id.x, meal, date) %>%
  summarise(step_sum = sum(steps))
```

The result is:

```
   id.x  meal date       step_sum
  <dbl> <int> <date>        <dbl>
1    13     1 2015-12-23      876
2    13     2 2015-12-23      294
```

**Edit 1**: You might also try using `data.table` for a faster solution. Using `setDT` will make the data.frame a data.table:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(mealsData)
setDT(sampleData)
```

Then, you can do a nonequi join between your `sampleData` and `mealsData`. This statement includes which columns you want to include in the result, and merging based on times. The `nomatch` will leave out results where there is no match (for example, no post-prandial glucose levels for second meal).

```
sampleData[!is.na(gl)][
  mealsData,
  .(id, phase, gl, x.time),
  on = .(id, phase, time >= postprandial_1, time <= postprandial_2),
  nomatch = 0]
```

To get the sum of steps, you can try:

```
sampleData[mealsData, 
           .(id, phase, meal, date, steps), 
           on = .(id, phase, time >= time, time <= postprandial_2), 
           nomatch = 0][
  , 
  .(step_sum = sum(steps)), 
  by = .(id, meal, date)]
```

The results should be the same as above.

**Edit 2**: You can merge both the second and third outcomes (average glucose and sum of steps). Make sure both have `id`, `phase`, `meal` and `date` to merge on. The first `dt1` now includes the mean glucose and stores the associated `meal`. Store both `dt1` and `dt2` in intermediate data.tables:

```
dt1 <- sampleData[!is.na(gl)][
  mealsData,
  .(id, phase, gl, x.time, meal, date),
  on = .(id, phase, time >= postprandial_1, time <= postprandial_2),
  nomatch = 0][
    ,
    .(gl_ave = mean(gl)), 
    by = .(id, phase, meal, date)]

dt2 <- sampleData[mealsData, 
           .(id, phase, meal, date, steps), 
           on = .(id, phase, time >= time, time <= postprandial_2), 
           nomatch = 0][
  , 
  .(step_sum = sum(steps)), 
  by = .(id, phase, meal, date)]
```

Then `merge`:

```
merge(dt1, dt2, by = c("id", "phase", "meal", "date"))
```

Comment: Hello @Ben, thank you for being so descriptive. I've been able to recreate your first fuzzy_inner_join with good results. Unfortunately, the runtime of the second fuzzy_inner_join is too long. I've stopped after 3 hours. My sampleData has ~650,000 rows, and mealsData generates ~3,000 rows. What would be a workaround for this?

Comment: The `data.table` and `sqldf` solutions likely would be faster (I alluded to those early on in the answer for this reason). Would you like me to edit the answer with one of these options? Happy to.

Comment: Yes please, it would help a lot if you could provide the code to the data.table and sqldf alternative(s).

Comment: @TIV Please see bottom of answer above with `data.table` option. Let me know if this helps and if you have questions.

Comment: @TIV Also, you may want to subset your data and try on 1,000 rows or so, just to check its performance and accuracy, before trying on full dataset.

Comment: thank you. Both `data.table` commands run well and generate results. The sum of steps results are quite similar to the results of @jamoreiras, in the answer below. How would I go about merging the tables from 2) and 3)? Essentially, for every meal I would like a row that includes the identifying info, glucose at meal, mean glucose 2h+-15min after meal, and sum of steps. Is there a way to get only a mean reading of glucose for the 2h+-15min timeframe in both 1) and 2)? That would make merging easier.

Comment: running the dplyr script for postprandial reaction on a subset of 1,000 rows took 45 seconds, i.e. would take ~8 hours for the whole dataset.

Comment: Yes, you can merge the two with `merge`. Make sure both have `id`, `phase`, `meal` and `date` to merge on. It does not have glucose at a given meal, since that was `NA` in your dataset, but that could be added as well when making the `mealsData` (and just carrying that value through). See edited answer (Edit 2).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Ben! Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your the data frame `sampleData` is sorted and includes one observation per minute this can be used in your advantage:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
```

**1)** Retrieve the rows with the first meal of the day of each participant (id), and their glucose reading 2 hours (+-15 minutes) **before** that meal:

```
sampleData$gl <- na.locf(sampleData$gl, na.rm=FALSE)

df1 <- sampleData %>% 
  mutate(previousGl = lag(gl,120), glTime = lag(time, 120)) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(kiloCalories))
```

**2)** Retrieve the rows with each meal (i.e. each kiloCalories entry) of each participant (id), along with the glucose reading 2 hours (+-15 minutes) after the meal.

```
sampleData$gl <- na.locf(sampleData$gl, fromLast = TRUE,na.rm=FALSE)

df2 <- sampleData %>% 
  mutate(previousGl = lag(gl,120), glTime = lead(time, 120)) %>%  
  filter(!is.na(kiloCalories))
```

**3)** From task 2, take the subset of data in between meal and glucose reading, and calculate the sum of steps within that time.

```
lapply(1:NROW(df2), function(i) {
  sampleData %>% filter(time >= df2$time[i], 
                        time <= df2$glTime[i]) %>%
    summarize(steps = sum(steps))
})
```

Comment: Hello @jamoreiras, thank you for your help. If I run your suggestions for 1) and 2) in sequence, they generate the same dataframes. If I 'reset' sampleData$gl to it's initial state before running 2), I get two differing data frames. These dataframes (df1 & df2) differ both in the gl column, and the previousGl column. I understand the difference in the previousGl column, but how can they have different gl readings for the same time? Can you help me interpret this?

Comment: First, you are correct, you are supposed to reset the dataframe between runs 1) and 2).

Comment: Second, there are readings of glucose  every 15 minutes. If the time of the meals is random and considering the margin of +/- 15 minutes you gave, than if we are looking for the glucose reading **after** the meal, we need to take the glucose reading from the next reading. Depending on the exact time of the meal, adding 2 hours, will get us always a reading 2 hours + 15 minutes if the meal was not on the exact hour, in which case is a reading 2 hours after the meal exactly.

Comment: This approach takes advantage we are dealing with an sorted dataframe with readings every minute. If that were not the case, the whole readings would be inaccurate. Still, df2 retrieves 2 lines for which the second line doesn’t get a reading even though there is a reading 15 minutes before we get to the 2 hours after the meal.